# How to implement FirebaseDB with a Django Web Application

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Am trying to implement Firebase Realtime Database with my Django Web Application. After properly setting up the configuration with Firebase, I got confused about how data will write into my Firebase Database from my Django website instead of using Sqlite, or Postgres.

Under `settings.py`, do I need to set my engine to Firebase? Am totally confused here. I do not want to use the normal ORM such as Sqlite, Postgres etc. I want my app to use Firebase.

Is there something else I need to understand about Firebase?

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

**pyrebase_settings** file

```
import pyrebase

config = {
    "apiKey": "my_api_key_is_here",
    "authDomain": "my_auth_domain_is_here",
    "databaseURL": "my_firebase_database_url_is_here",
    "projectId": "my_firebase_project_id_is_here",
    "storageBucket": "my_firebase_storageBucket_is_here",
    "serviceAccount": "my_serviceAccount.json_file_path_is_here",
    "messagingSenderId": "messagingSenderId_is_here"
}

# initialize app with config
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

# authenticate a user
auth = firebase.auth()
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password("email@usedforauthentication.com", "FstrongPasswordHere")


db = firebase.database()
```

Answer (score 13):

take a look at the [database](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#database) section of the doc. It details how you would interact with the database API. Typically you would use these in your views where you need to save or retrieve something from the database.

e.g say you want a view that gets users, you could have something like this:

```
#views.py
from pyrebase_settings import db, auth
from django.shortcuts import render

def get_users(request):
    users = db.child("users").get()
    return render(request, 'users.html', {'users': users.val()})
```

The documentation for retrieving data can be seen [here](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#retrieve-data)

also say you want a view to save(signup) users, you could have something like so:

```
#views.py
from pyrebase_settings import db, auth

def signup(request):
   form = SignupForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
       email = form.cleaned_data('email')
       password = form.cleaned_data('password')
       auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
   # the rest of your code goes here
```

the `create_user_with_email_and_password` method is documented [here](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#creating-users)

PS. I have never made use of the pyrebase library so I write only based on what is specified in its docs. Also I am only writing these django snippets off the top of my head so forgive me if there are any syntax errors or typos :)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP wants to use Firebase as the primary data store "instead of using Sqlite, or Postgres". Stock Django cannot do this.

Comment: @PaulBissex My answer doesn't say anything about sqlite or postgres. My answer literally explains how they can use pyrebase with django views

Answer (score 8):

> Is there something else I need to understand about Firebase?

No, there is something you need to understand about Django -- **it is designed to use a relational database engine as its primary data store**. Firebase is not relational.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Many answers on this question are missing this point, and suggesting code or libraries that let you *access Firebase from Python*. Sure, that's possible. But that **doesn't make it work as a primary data store for Django**. Django's ORM features and contrib apps all presume a relational database.

In order for this to work you'd need something along the lines of [django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/) that supported Firebase. As far as I know that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

consider having a look at the fcm-django library here https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP wants to use Firebase as the primary data store "instead of using Sqlite, or Postgres".

Answer (score 0):

My solution for getting multiple files from html and upload that files in firebase storage in web django

index.html

```
<div id="fine-uploader-manual-trigger">
<input class="custom-file" type="file" name="imgname" id="productImgUpload" accept=".xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc,audio/*,.docx,video/*,.ppt,.pptx,.txt,.pdf" multiple>
</div>
```

views.py

```
from firebase import Firebase

def storeimg(request):
  config = {
            "apiKey": "",
            "authDomain": "",
            "databaseURL": "",
            "storageBucket": ""
        }
  firebase = Firebase(config)
  storage = firebase.storage()
  finalimglist = []
  imglist = []
  for i in range(len(filepath)):
       storage.child("Product/"+cname+"/"+str(filepath[i])).put(filepath[i])
       imgurl = storage.child("Product/"+cname+"/"+str(filepath[i])).get_url(token='null')
       imglist.append(imgurl)

  finalimglist.append(imglist)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP wants to use Firebase as the primary data store "instead of using Sqlite, or Postgres".

Answer (score -1):

Pyrebase is a wrapper around the Firebase for python. I don't recommend using Pyrebase because it lags support for Firestore and FCM. When everything in Django is done on Serverside, why not use the **Firebase Admin SDK** on the Django server. You can also manage users with it. I mean there is good documentation for adding the Firebase to our server. Also, they have docs in Python, NodeJS etc., for the server. I know its kind of going towards API stuff. But I feel its the right way to do in Django since Django is a server application. Check out this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP wants to use Firebase as the primary data store "instead of using Sqlite, or Postgres".

Comment: It's important to note that Firebase is not directly supported by Django. However, Firebase supports Python which you can use on the serverside with Admin SDK. I hope that clarifies. For more info, check out this video by JenPerson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yylnC3dr_no